# Can chrome extension background call a function defined in popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here is my manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
  "tabs"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }       
}
```

In my index.html I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>  
</head>    
<body>
    <div class="container">            
</div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

and in my script.js I have:

```
var Chat = function( username, avatar) {
    username = username || "";
 /// more lines
}
```

Is there a way I call the Chat(index.html) in my backround.js 
ex:

```
  chat = new Chat("john", "");
```

A more generic question would be: How does popup and background can speak together ? With messaging ? any available sample ?

Comment: Please explain the logic you're trying to implement more. A good answer depends on that.

Comment: The background needs to connect to chat to display number of connected people in a badge and chat is implemented in index.

Comment: You probably should keep the chat engine IN the background. The popup gets destroyed the moment it's closed.

Comment: ok... But how will the bakcground js then call the script.js function such as addUser or addText ?
How will it output something into the popup HTML ?

Comment: You can include script.js in your background: `"scripts": ["script.js", "background.js"]` and communicate with the popup using [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging).

Comment: I have read that already, but I have no idea how background.js will send a message to the opened popup.
As simple as : chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"});

And what happens if popup is not opened: it does not receive any message ?